# R: replace all values in a dataframe lower than a threshold with NA

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to replace all values in a dataframe lower than a given threshold `minval` with `NA`. What would be the most elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
 df[df<minval]=NA
```

`df < minval` creates a boolean matrix, which is used to select the values you want to replace with `NA`.

Comment: Ha yes of course - I got confused trying with which(...) - this works perfectly - thanks!