# Conditional replacement of values in a R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, masking, data-masking

I wanted to mask any values under 5 in my R dataframe and was looking for a solution to do it in one go for the entire dataframe.

Comment: Include the data in the question. Also, I think this has been asked before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26468385/r-replace-all-values-in-a-dataframe-lower-than-a-threshold-with-na and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54226974/replace-values-greater-than-zero-with-1-in-r are few of the links.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Data<- data.frame(
                 Age_band= c("0-14","15-19","20-29","30-39","40-49","50-59","60-69","70-79","80+"),
                 Number_of_participants = c(2,53,31,11,75,35,37,3,12),
                 )
    
    Data[Data<5] = "<5"
```